# CakePHP - Custom login check

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP's default $this->Auth->login() script to login users. This works fine I just want to extend the actions so that it checks in the DB if the user's field for is_active is set to 1. If it is 0 I want to kick it to an error page and not log them in.

What is the best approach to implement this?

Im running CakePHP v. 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

There is something called scope:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

There is even the very same examaple in the documentation.